# Getting each letter in a String only once

Tags: java, char

I'm writing a Java program for Horspool's algorithm, and am having a bit of trouble.  I'm trying to create an array of chars that will hold each letter in a string, but I don't want duplicates of the letters.  Right now this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner (System.in);

    int count = 0;

    int count2 = 0;

    int inc = 0;

    //The text to search for the phrase in
    String t = "";

    //The phrase/pattern to search for
    String p = "";

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println("Harspool's Algorithm: ");
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Please enter the full text: ");
    t = scanIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the pattern to search for: ");
    p = scanIn.nextLine();

    char[] text = new char[t.length()];
    char[] pattern = new char[p.length()];
    char[] alphabet = new char[t.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++)
    {
        alphabet[i] = ' ';
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        text[i] = t.charAt(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++)
    {
        pattern[i] = p.charAt(i);
    }

    while (inc < text.length)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < text.length; j++)
        {
            if (text[inc] != alphabet[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == p.length() - 1 && count2 < text.length)
            {
                alphabet[count2] = text[inc];
                count2++;
                count = 0;
                inc++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(alphabet[i]);
    }
}
```

I believe the problem is in the while loop, but I can't figure out what exactly is going wrong. Right now, it will print out the entire string passed in, when it should be printing each letter only once.  Could someone please help?

Comment: Can you give example of input text, input pattern, and the correct output?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of counting the occurrences of each character, Use `Set<Character>`. A set contains unique elements and so you will not have duplicates that way.

You can also convert a `Set` to an array by doing `mySet.toArray(new String[mySet.size()]);` or just `mySet.toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: Seems to be homework to me. If not, yes, use `Set` and maximize happiness.

Comment: Would I implement this in this way:?

Set<Character> mySet = new Set<Character>(t);

Where t is the string the user inputs?

Thanks!

Comment: @Mouse, no, you would still have to iterate over the characters in the string and then add them to the `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not easy to read. You might consider using the following algorithm instead.

```
int ccount[256];
int ii;
for(ii=0;ii<256;ii++) ccount[ii]=0;
for (ii = 0; ii < text.length; ii++)
{
    ccount[t.charAt(i)%256]++;
}
for (ii = 0; ii<256; ii++) {
    if(ccount[ii]>0) System.out.printf("%c", ii);
}
```

EDIT - made sure `ccount` was initialized, and captured characters outside of range 0-255 with `%` operator.